# YouTube videos not available in Rekonq

Tags: video, browser, youtube, rekonq

YouTube videos are not working on my Ubuntu 12.04.
Most of the videos say "Video not available at this moment", but if you go to someones channel, it says "undefinded" but displays audio.

Browser is rekonq, but happens in every browser I have on Ubuntu.
Help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: do you have shockwave flash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal, you have to install the flash plugin, by going to tools, add-ons, and then you should see plugins. click on this. search shockwave flash and there it should be. Click install and when it is done the problem should be fixed